# RYU Controller with ARP Loop - Mininet

Tags: python, api, mininet, arp, ryu

[Loop Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQMlq.png)

I dunno how to manage the ARP loop in this mininet topology. I have written the topology code using Python API and use the simple_switch.py Ryu controller, but I cannot still ping the h1 to h2. Can anyone able to help?

Comment: I can send you the code if you need it. just provide your email. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A multipath router Ryu app is required as discussed elsewhere:

https://wildanmsyah.wordpress.com/2018/01/21/testing-ryu-multipath-routing-with-load-balancing-on-mininet/

https://github.com/muzixing/ryu/tree/master/ryu/app/multipath